React JS Scheduler Drag and Drop Issue: Dropping on Incorrect Target
I'm developing a scheduler in React JS with a drag-and-drop feature. My setup includes a table where each  is a droppable area, and I can drag and drop  elements into these cells. However, I'm encountering a couple of issues with the drag-and-drop functionality:
Incorrect Target Issue: When I drag and drop a , it sometimes gets dropped into the wrong . It appears that the drop target is not being correctly identified.
Lag in Drag Update: I've also observed that the drop position updates seem to be one drag event behind. For example, if I drag a  to a new cell, it drops it at the position of the previous drag event instead of the current one.
Here's a simplified version of my code:
   const timeSlots = ["06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24"];


 const DraggableEvent = ({ event, children }) => {
    const [{ isDragging }, drag, preview] = useDrag(() => ({
      type: 'event',
      item: { event },
      collect: (monitor) => ({
        isDragging: monitor.isDragging(),
      }),
    }),[dropTime]);
  
    return (
      <>
        <div
          ref={drag}
          style={{ opacity: isDragging ? 0 : 1, cursor: 'move' }}
          className="draggable-event"
        >
          {children}
        </div>
        {isDragging && (
          <div
            ref={preview}
            style={{
              position: 'absolute',
              top: 0,
              left: 0,
              pointerEvents: 'none',
              zIndex: 1000,
              opacity: 0,
              trasition:'all .3s'
            }}
          >
            {children}
          </div>
        )}
      </>
    );
  };
  
  const DroppableCell = ({ id, time, courtItem, children, rawEvent, isBooked }) => {
    const [{ isOver }, drop] = useDrop(
      () => ({
        accept: 'event',
        drop: (item) => {
          console.log('Dropped item:', item); // Debugging log
          console.log('rawEvent:', rawEvent); // Debugging log
          const diff = calculateTimeDifferenceInHours(item.event.start_time, item.event.end_time);
          setDropTime({
            id: item.id,
            station_id: item.event.station_id,
            start_time: `${time}:00:00`,
            end_time: `${parseInt(time) + 1}:00:00`,
          });
          onEventDrop(item, `${time}:00:00`, `${parseInt(time) + 1}:00:00`, courtItem.title, diff);
        },
        collect: (monitor) => ({
          isOver: monitor.isOver(),
        }),
      }),
      [courtItem, time]
    );
  
    console.log(JSON.stringify(courtItem.program_schedules.length > 0));
    return (
      <td
        id={id} // Set the unique ID here
        ref={drop}
        onClick={() => courtItem.program_schedules.length === 0 && handleShowModal(rawEvent)}
        width={50}
        className={`dropable-cell border ${isOver ? 'bg-yellow-200' : ''}`}
      >
        {children}
      </td>
    );
  };

this is the table I perform drag and drop thing
<table className="w-full">
                <thead>
                  <tr className="mb-3 text-center">
                    {timeSlots.map((i, index) => (
                      <th key={index} className="color-slate-300 h-[50px] w-[30px] border-2 border-slate-300 bg-white">
                        {i}
                      </th>
                    ))}
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody className="position-relative">
                  {court.map((courtItem, courtIndex) => (
                    <>
                      {loginState.user_type !== "academy"&&<CurrentTime startTime={courtItem.station_start_time} endTime={courtItem.station_end_time} />}
                      <tr key={courtIndex} className="w-100 z-0 mb-3">
                        {timeSlots.map((time, timeIndex) => {
                          const isBooked = courtItem.program_schedules.find(
                            (booking) => booking.start_time === `${time}:00:00`
                          );
                          const timeRange = isBooked && calculateTimeDifferenceInHours(isBooked.start_time, isBooked.end_time);
        
                          return (
                            <DroppableCell
                              key={`${courtIndex}-${timeIndex}`} // Generate a unique ID
                              id={`${courtIndex}-${timeIndex}`} // Pass the unique ID
                              time={time}
                              courtItem={courtItem}
                              rawEvent={isBooked}
                              isBooked={isBooked}
                            >
                              {isBooked && (
                                <DraggableEvent event={isBooked}>
                                  <div
                                    style={{
                                      border: '1px solid #000',
                                      background: `${isBooked?.program?.color_code}`,
                                      width: tdWidth * timeRange,
                                    }}
                                    className={`position-absolute color-slate-300 eventHolder left-0 top-0 z-10 h-[50px] cursor-pointer border-2 border-white text-center hover:rounded-lg hover:bg-green-400
                                      ${isBooked?.status_id === 0 && 'active_slot rounded-lg border border-opacity-50 bg-green-400'}
                                      ${isBooked?.status_id === 1 && 'active_slot_1 pointer-events-none rounded-lg border bg-green-200'}
                                      ${isBooked?.status_id === 2 && 'active_slot_2 pointer-events-none rounded-lg border bg-slate-400'}
                                    `}
                                    onClick={() => {
                                      setbookingInfo(isBooked);
                                      const startDate = new Date(updatedDate.date);
                                      startDate.setHours(time, 0, 0, 0);
                                      const endDate = new Date(updatedDate.date);
                                      endDate.setHours(parseInt(time) + 1, 0, 0, 0);
                                      setRawEvent({
                                        schedule_id: isBooked?.id,
                                        schedule_date: updatedDate.date,
                                        start: startDate.toString(),
                                        end: endDate.toString(),
                                        court_id: courtItem.id,
                                        resourceId: courtItem.id,
                                        booking_id: isBooked?.id,
                                      });
                                      createBooking(courtItem.id, updatedDate, time, parseInt(time) + 1, isBooked);
                                    }}
                                  ></div>
                                </DraggableEvent>
                              )}
                            </DroppableCell>
                          );
                        })}
                      </tr>
                    </>
                  ))}
                </tbody>
              </table>

Questions:

Why is the drop target sometimes incorrect, and how can I ensure
that the  is dropped into the intended ?
What might be
causing the lag in the drop position update, and how can I fix it to
ensure the drop is always current?

Additional Info:
I'm using react-dnd with the HTML5Backend.
The problem occurs consistently in my development environment.
Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve these issues would be greatly appreciated!
